# tf.data.Dataset with stepping batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a temporal dataset of 8760 samples. I wonder if there is a way to batch it with a step of 1, that is: the first batch contains the No.1 to 4, the second batch contains the No.2 to 5, the third batch contains the No.3 to 6 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have only 8760 samples, you probably can afford (in terms of RAM costs) the simplest possible solution - just transform your data using ordinary Python code:

```
dataset = [sample1, sample2, ... sample8760]
transformed_dataset = []
for i in range(len(dataset) - 3):
    transformed_dataset.append(dataset[i:i + 4])
```

If you can't afford to store your dataset in memory, try using generator function (since TF 2.1 you may pass generators directly to `model.fit()`:

```
def dataset_generator():
     for i in range(len(dataset) - 3):
         yield dataset[i:i + 4]
```

Comment: it's my first time start a question. Could your see if i did it right?